# What makes a bacterium move away from a neutrophil cell?

Tags: immunology, immune-system

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_xh-bkiv_c) we see a bacterium seemingly moving away from the neutrophil that is chasing it. What mechanism makes it "want" to avoid the neutrophil? It doesn't seem to mind being around other cells of the same organism. Why does it react differently to a neutrophil?

Comment: In the video doesn't it look like it's just moving passively in the solution? As the neutrophil moves around it displaces solution that has to go somewhere, and the third dimension is impeded on the microscope slide. Like when you try to scoop something from your soup and it gets pushed away by your spoon.

Comment: yes, it seems it does. This makes the question obsolete